# Force download all files in a folder

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am trying to get all the files in a particular folder to force download:

I created a .htaccess file but this does not work

```
AddHandler cgi-script .php .pl .py .jsp .asp .htm .shtml .sh .cgi 
Options -ExecCGI
```

Basically, I don't want any script or anything to execute. I want everything to download from that folder.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it on an extension by extension basis with [AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler)

```
AddHandler default-handler php pl py jsp asp
```

However this is cumbersome as you need to keep on top of every possible extension. You can set the default handler for every file within a htaccess file with [SetHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#sethandler). And this would be my preferred method. Simply enter this into your htaccess file.

```
SetHandler default-handler
```

If you don't have permissions to do this in your htaccess, you'll need to get it entered in a Directory directive in your Apache configuration:

```
<Directory /path/to/dir>
    SetHandler default-handler
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution to download ALL the files in a folder.

.htaccess in that folder

```
Header set Content-Disposition attachment
```

But this needs Headers module to be loaded in apache

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

and one more thing Browser cached images won't download.