# Apache: create a file directory, without file parsing

Tags: apache-2.2

I've created a public directory where people can upload files to and I'd like to disable any kind of file parsing in that directory, i.e. disable php file parsing, .htaccess, etc. The directory should only contain images and compressed archives.

I was wanting to use the RemoveHandler, but I'd like a simple way to disable all the security threats.

Currently I'm using this but I wonder if this is enough:

```
<Directory "/var/www/dir">
Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
AddHandler default-handler php pl py
AllowOverride None
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

just

```
SetHandler default-handler
```

instead of [AddHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#AddHandler) should be more generic [ especially that probably your web server/mod-php will happily execute .php3 and .php5 files. maybe even .phtml ].

interestingly such syntax of [SetHandler](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_mime.html#AddHandler) but apparently works for me [ found via: [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/83915/force-download-all-files-in-a-folder) ]

i'd also change [Directory](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#directory) into [Location](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#location) so it's not bound to some branch of your filesystem, but rather virtual directory in apache's url. - just in case..

you might also add

```
DirectoryIndex index.html
```

in case someone wanted to host circa '95 all-static webpage...

Comment: That's also the link I found, which taught me about SetHandler. I tried AddHandler at first but it didn't respect my Options Indexes FollowSymLinks configuration, it gave me a "not found" error instead when trying to view the contents of the directory. Oh, and my server only executes .php files.